# Django Python shell import problem [From app.models import Model] is not working

Tags: python, django

redcube/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Redcube(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Images(models.Model):
    redcube = models.ForeignKey(Redcube, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.redcube.name


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    level = models.IntegerField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Basic(models.Model):
    basic = models.ManyToManyField(Redcube, through='Inventorytest', blank=True)


class Inventorytest(models.Model):
    redcube = models.ForeignKey(Redcube, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    images = models.ForeignKey(Images, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    basic = models.ForeignKey(Basic, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

class testuser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    level = models.IntegerField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

from the python shell

```
>>> from redcube.models import Profile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'Profile' from 'redcube.models' (/Users/macos/basic/btp/btp/redcube/models.py)
>>> from redcube.models import Images
>>> Images.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Images: Hawaii>, <Images: City view hotel>, <Images: Cottage>, <Images: Redcube>, <Images: Phone>, <Images: Flower>, <Images: Miho>]>
```

When I try to import and test the models in the python shell
Other model class is working right. but the Profile class is not working!

I've tried the from .models import Profile, but not working.
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Your indentation looks suspicious.

Comment: Thx :) I've done the edit!

Comment: The bad indentation would actually explain the error.

Comment: Can you still find the bad indentation? It's not working~!

Comment: what is Redcube? do you import it from different model, I'm trying to replicate the issue.

Comment: Try switching `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` with `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model` and then use `get_user_model()` instead of `user`. Like this you know for sure you're hooked up to the correct model.

Comment: Sorry, I've added the full code!

Comment: redcube is the django APPNAME~!

Comment: I've tried the get_user_model() to the model class but it still shows me the same error. Can not import the model in the python shell..

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue, but I couldn't make it, the code work fine and import without any errors, even I created app called redcube but it was the same... whats your Django version? and python version?

Comment: Only the Profile class and the testuser class is not possible to import on the shell. The other class's are fine to import :(

Comment: Ah!!!!! I fount the issue.

Comment: When I've added some new classes, I didn't exit the python shell. I've used 2 terminals at the same time for the python shell + django migrate!

Comment: PLS don´t use `User` at `ForeignKey`. You are running into lot of problems. You have to use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` . The [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) explains it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the pycharm.

I've used 2 terminals at the same time.
When I add class on the models.py, I have done the makemigrations & migrate

But I did not exit the python shell.

When I exit the python shell after the migrate, and start the python shell agian.

It worked :)

thanks for the help guys~!

Comment: Great, but I think you have to close the question, cause your question not point to a issue, it's just mistake of using a tool.